# How to limit memory usage during tar

Tags: linux, tar

I need to tar (or otherwise zip) more than 2.7 million files. (150GB)

However, with this many files the tar command uses way too much memory and my system crashes. What can I do?

```
tar -cf /path/filename.tar /path_to_file/
```

I've tried to do it in batches (multiple tar files would be OK) based on file creation date and `find`, but `find` takes up even more memory.

Comment: How much memory does tar use in the first case?  How much memory is available on the system?

Comment: How directory structure looks like, all files in top level directory? What is the file system? What is the output of *df -i*?

Comment: Have you tried a `tar -c /path_to_file | pv -L 3k > out.tar`?

Comment: Are you sure you're not actually writing the file to RAM, e.g. to a `/tmp` set up as tmpfs, or while running from a livecd?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is an answer exactly, as it doesn't say how to explicitly lower tar's memory usage, but...

I think you can specify the compression program used with tar to use `pigz` (parallel `gzip`), then specify the number of threads to use to better help manage memory. Maybe something like:

```
tar cvf - paths-to-archive | pigz -p 4 > archive.tar.gz
```

where `-p $NUM` is the number of cores.

Comment: I guess the problem is the file page cache, not CPU consumption where threads may help

Comment: You're totally right. My train of thought wasn't on the right path. Should I remove this answer?